# What is this bird nest for and why does it glow?

Tags: far-cry-primal

I've recently picked up Far Cry Primal and have been exploring the huge map. While running around, I found this bird nest that was shimmering and glowing like it's and interactable object in the game.

[image: bird nest]

What is the point of it? It didn't give me the option to interact with it, yet it glows like any other object in the world you can interact with (the white shimmer is visible on the left side of the nest, it was difficult to capture a screenshot of it completely).

The nest can be found in the lower portion of the map. It was past a waterfall that you walk under. I've included a screenshot of the exact location on the world map below:

[image: nest location]

Also, setting the nest on fire did nothing, which is why it looks burnt in the picture, and the nest was empty when I found it.

Comment: I don't have the game, but from what google is saying when I search for info on bird nests, it seems like it could potentially be related to birds you can hunt for feathers? Maybe if you stick around, some will show up?

Comment: @Vemonus it's possible that's the case, but I didn't see any birds in the sky which also show up on the mini map.  I also added to my question that the nest was empty when I found it.  I think feathers have a chance to spawn in nest, but the only time I saw that was during a mission where you had to go to specific nest to get rare feathers, so I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Comment: Maybe the feathers burned up in the fire *(you monster)*

Comment: @Vemonus lol no the nest was empty before I lit it up. I promise!

Answer (score 3):

It's part of a quest to gather eagle feathers for one of your tribesmen, and becomes interactive at that time. You first need to progress in the game and trigger the quest.